# SQL Server 2008 Trace Flag 4135

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone have any idea what this flag does? There is no reference to it on MSDN. It is not a part of the [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx) that lists available trace flags in 2008.

There is a  KB article that recommends that it is turned on to resolve a specific issue with SQL Server 2008 that we have run into, but we would like to at least know what this flag does before enabling it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960770

Comment: Seems that it's not to be documented, like many trace flags. I left a comment on the support page. Who knows...

Comment: I'm failing also.  I left a comment, too, asking for explanation of the flag.  Power in numbers, eh?

Comment: Me too         :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get an answer to this with the help of Jonathan Kehayias on the MSDN forums.

*The traceflag disables an optimization in the query optimizer. The 
optimization caused the issue described in the KB article when you try to 
insert into a table by selecting from the table itself.
As turning on the traceflag could result in a perf degradation, you only 
should use it if you run into the issue described in the KB article.*

The thread discussing this is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9ea718c2-e0e0-40cf-b12b-3269130448b7).

Comment: Top man       !

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, I'm thinking this turns on the hotfix included in Cumulative Update 3 should your system encounter the specific issue described in the knowledge base article.